# How to get better logging of EJB annotation replacement from GlassFish?

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb

I'm learning EJB as I go along, and one of the biggest problems I find is that my annotations sometimes do not work. For instance, I have in an `@Entity`:

```
@EJB(beanName="EventTriggerQueue") TriggerQueueAbst evq;
```

With:

```
@Local
public interface TriggerQueueAbst {
    public void queue(Object obj, Map<String, String> outputs);
}
```

And:

```
@Stateless
public class EventTriggerQueue implements Serializable, TriggerQueueAbst {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 5038081840391929418L;

  // JMS Queue declaration
  @Resource(mappedName="jms/MyFactory")
  private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

  @Resource(mappedName="jms/EventTriggerQueue")
  private Queue etQueue;

  @Override
  public void queue(Object evpObj, Map<String, String> outputs) {
    //....
  }
}
```

However, when I put a breakpoint on:

```
evq.queue(obj, outputs);
```

`evq` is just `null`, not a proxy. Is it possible to enable more detailed logging information that will show why the `@EJB` was ignored or skipped?

Comment: Do you really try to inject into an `@Entity`? Even if this is possible you shouldn't do that...

Comment: I realised that afterwards... I have redesigned my code so I no longer need to do this.